# Executing a command line process works on device but not on the emulator

Tags: android, android-ndk

I run the x264 command line encoder from native code using execl:

```
execl("/bin/sh", "sh", "-c", "/data/data/com.mycompany.myapp/files/components/x264enc5/x264enc5", NULL);
```

It works fine on device (Nexus 7 with Android 4.2.2), but on the emulator (tried 4.0.3 and 4.2.2) I'm getting this in the log:

> F/libc    (  783): Fatal signal 4 (SIGILL) at 0x00000000
>   (code=268435456)
>
> I/DEBUG   (   34): *****  ** *****  ** *****  ** *****  ** ***
>
> ---
>
> I/DEBUG   (   34): Build fingerprint:
>   'generic/sdk/generic:4.0.4/MR1/302030:eng/test-keys'
>
> I/DEBUG   (   34): pid: 783, tid: 783  >>>
>   /data/data/com.mycompany.myapp/files/components/x264enc5/x264enc5
>   <<<
>
> I/DEBUG   (   34): signal 4 (SIGILL), code 1 (ILL_ILLOPC), fault addr
>   000c3d68

Does anyone know what could be a possible reason for this problem?

Comment: I wonder if you're using an ARM compiled executable on Intel emulator or vice versa?

Comment: x264 is compiled with --host=arm-linux. Emulator is running with ARM CPU

Comment: "ARM" is hardly a single target - you could for example be using hardware acceleration extensions not supported by the emulator.